What parts replaced Honda Civic 9th Gen Rear coil springs 52446-TR0-A12 and 52441-TR0-A12?
The parts on hondapartsnow.com that correspond to my rear left and right coil springs are,
52446-TR0-A12 - LEFT
52441-TR0-A12 - RIGHT

However, I can't find these online anywhere? Did Honda change the part numbers? I can't find a third party OEM either that maps to them?
I have a 2012 Honda Civic Ex.
Who makes the rear springs for it, and what are the current model numbers?
